# I want to authenticate Spring Security OAuth2 with access_token only

Tags: spring, security, oauth-2.0, access-token

I am curious about two things when using the Spring Security OAuth2 method.

1. Is it possible to perform authentication by checking the access_token every time without using JSESSION or jwtToken?
   As an example, the first time, access_token and refresh_token are issued through OAuth2 authentication and stored in JDBC (mysql).
   In subsequent requests, I would like to retrieve the access_token stored in mysql and determine its validity.
2. If the access_token has expired in Spring Security OAuth2 method, where is the code to issue a new access_token using refresh_token and update it in JDBC (mysql)?

Answer (score 0):

Your question has very little to do with Spring. It is mostly about OAuth2 (whatever the framework implementing it) and you obviously need more background about OAuth2.

***Resource owners*** are authenticated on an ***OAuth2 authorization server*** for a given ***OAuth2 client*** so that this client can get get tokens and authorize its requests to ***OAuth2 resource server***. Which of this actors is your question about, exactly? Authorization server, client and resource server are usually different applications and the 3 can be written with Spring.

***Clients*** (from which you initiate login and which stores tokens) and ***authorization server*** (which performs login and issues tokens) need sessions to run the `authorization_code` flow (not for that only, but this flow is what is used to "login" a user) and there is little you can do about that. ***Resource servers*** (which use tokens for access control decision) can be configured without session (stateless), and frequently are because it makes it very easy to scale and fault tolerant (any instance can process any request and you can replace any instance by any other at any moment).

`HttpSessionOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository`, the default Spring Security implementation, stores tokens in session, just because it is a very good option at many regards (much faster than database, and also safer). As usual with Spring, you can write your own `OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository` implementation using a database, but you'll have degraded performance (and maybe security issues). If the concern is to share tokens across client instances, consider that it's probably faster that each instance get its own token, and also that there is a `spring-session` project to share session data across instances.

There are two options for validating tokens on ***OAuth2 resource servers***: JWT decoding and introspection. The second involves a round trip to the ***authorization server*** for each request, which seems to be what you are looking for in 1st question, but this has serious performance impact. Also, it brings nothing in terms of security if ***OAuth2 clients*** are implemented correctly: a "safe" client should be confidential (run on a server you trust and authenticated with a secret) and delete tokens when a user logs out (it should not be necessary to check for each request if the session was closed on the authorization server, the session on the client should always be in the same state). And even if one of the ***authorization server*** or the ***client*** is not implementing the Back-Channel Logout (which is the case of Spring clients until Security 6.2.0 is released), for the ***client*** session to be valid after the session on the ***authorization server*** was invalidated, you must be in SSO configuration (several OAuth2 clients sharing the same authorization server), having a user logging out using ***another client***, and be between this logout and the access token expiration, which should be a short duration (probably less than 5 minutes).

In Spring security, the abstraction for an OAuth2 client with tokens is "authorized client". You might start with `OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager` to explore the source code if you want to understand the internals of tokens acquisition and refreshing.